# partion on date column + X days

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, partitioning

Trying to drop duplicate transactions by account and date, that may have ocurred on the same date or within 10 days of the original transaction date. Also need to drop some test transaction data. Have code that will identify the first transaction by datetime,date and account but not sure how I can improve it to capture the incremental 10 days.

Data set

```
datetime            date        account  secondaryaccount
2023-03-25 16:25:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-02-18 16:15:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-02-09 16:48:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-02-03 16:46:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-02-03 16:45:58 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-02-03 16:45:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-02-03 12:05:18 2023-02-03  4321     654321
```

Current Output

```
datetime            date        account  secondaryaccount
2023-02-03 16:45:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-02-18 16:15:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-02-09 16:48:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-03-25 16:25:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
```

Expected Output

```
timedate            date        account  secondaryaccount
2023-03-25 16:25:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-02-18 16:15:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
2023-02-03 16:45:18 2023-02-03  1234     123456
```

Working Code

```
 select *
 from (
        select *, 
                row_number() over(partition by date, account 
                order by datetime) as row_num
        from data)
                where row_num = 1 and secondaryaccount not in (654321,765432);
```